# request URL from browser or server

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, url-routing, json.net

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/xyz.Web/Incls/ctrls/main/dtactrl/Data.aspx",
```

now whenever I will push this on QA,DEV, OR PROD the xyz.Web is going to change but the remaining stream will remain same so is there a way to request the URI and paste it dynamically rather then hard coding the URL field??
 need some right direction to make it more efficient..thanks

Comment: Could you instead of using absolute url use a url that is relative to the page? That would eliminate the need to change xyz.Web

Comment: Either generate the script dynamically ( based on server settings ) or  generate HTML dynamically and create URL inside it and read it with JavaScript.

Comment: hmm will this work??? ~/Incls/ctrls/main/dtactrl/Data.aspx

Comment: @Scorpio Only if it will work in your browser url bar after the `protocol:domain/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     url:'<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Incls/ctrls/main/dtactrl/Data.aspx") %>',
```

I just wanted to update this if in case anyone else comes across this issue..This solved my issue..